# Keystone.js filtering on related fields within own model

Tags: keystonejs

I am working on filtering my subsection selection to display only subSections that are related to the current mainNavigationSection. Each of these subsections also has a mainNavigation section. For some reason the current implementation is not returning any results.

Here is my Page Model:

```
Page.add({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  mainNavigationSection: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'NavItem', refPath: 'key', many: true, index: true },
  subSection: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'SubSection', filters: { mainNavigationSection:':mainNavigationSection' }, many: true, index: true, note: 'lorem ipsum' },
  state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'draft', index: true },
  author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', index: true }
}
```

Here is my subSectionModel:

```
SubSection.add({
  name: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
  mainNavigationSection: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'NavItem', many: true, required: true, initial: true},
  showInFooterNav: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  defaultPage: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Page' },
  description: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 150, hint: 'optional description' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems, you have the possibility of many `mainNavigationSections` on your model. You'd have to iterate over each of them on the current `Page`, and find the related `SubSections`. You'll need to use the [async Node module](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to run all the queries and get the results from each.

```
var async  = require('async');
var pID    = req.params.pid; // Or however you are identifying the current page
keystone.list('Page').model.findOne({page: pID}).exec(function (err, page) {
    if (page && !err) {
        async.each(page.mainNavigationSection, function (curMainNavigationSection, cb) {
            keystone.list('SubSection').model
            .find({mainNavigationSection: curMainNavigationSection._id.toString()})
            .exec(function (err2, curSubSections) {
                if (curSubSections.length !== 0 && !err2) {
                    // Do what you need to do with the navigation subSections here
                    // I recommend using a local variable, which will persist through
                    // every iteration of this loop and into the callback function in order
                    // to persist data
                    return cb(null)
                }
                else {
                    return cb(err || "An unexpected error occurred.");
                }
            });
       }, function (err) {
           if (!err) {
               return next(); // Or do whatever
           }
           else {
               // Handle error 
           }
       });
    }
    else {
       // There were no pages or you have an error loading them
    }
});
```